# I Need to add two commands to one button how should i do?

Tags: python, flet

I am a beginner and i want to add two commands to one button. I am using flet in python..

please help me and please show this fix.. i am a begginner in flet and the docs arent helping me it would be really helpful if you guys help me

Here is the Source code:

```
from flet import *
import flet as ft 
import random
from twilio import Client
def main(page:Page):
    page.title = "Medidost UI Test #1"
    #def btn_clicked(e):
        otp = random.randint(0,9999999)

        account_sid = '***************' # SORRY CANNOT SHARE 
        auth_token = '*************************' # SORRY CANNOT SHARE 
        client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

        messages = client.messages.create(
            body = f"Your OTP for Medidost Sign Up IS {otp}",
            from_ = '+14845099091',
            #to= n
        )
    def route_change(e: RouteChangeEvent) -> None:
        page.views.clear()
    #Home Page
        page.views.append(
            View(
                route='/',
                controls=[
                AppBar(title=Text('Home'), bgcolor="blue"),
                Image(src='untitled.png'),
                Text('Welcome To Medidost. To Continue to the app please sign up', size=30),
                ElevatedButton(text="Go to Home Screen", on_click= btn_clicked, lambda _: page.go('/home')) #<-Want to add two Commands here...#
                ],
                vertical_alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                horizontal_alignment=CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                spacing=26
            )

        )
    #Home Page
        if page.route == "/home":
            page.views.append(
                View(
                    route='/home',
                    controls=[
                        AppBar(title=Text('Testing if this Works...'), bgcolor="blue"),
                        Text('Home', size=30),
                        ElevatedButton(text="Go to SignUp Screen", on_click=lambda _: page.go('/'))
                    ]
                )
            )
    page.update()

    def view_pop(e: ViewPopEvent)-> None:
        page.views.pop()
        top_view: View = page.views[-1]
        page.go(top_view.route)
    
    page.on_route_change = route_change
    page.on_view_pop = view_pop
    page.go(page.route)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ft.app(target=main)
```

i tried but it gives this error

SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Answer (score 0):

You can put both functions within the lambda function.
Example:

```
on_click=lambda e:(btn_clicked(e),page.go('/home'))
```